# How to fix the Power query code error for splitting a text column based on a criteria

Tags: powerquery, m

Split the text values in a column based on the data type of the first character in each record.

I need to have the new (custom) column return the text before the first " " delimiter if the first character of the text is a number, otherwise return "0,".

```
If Value.Is(Text.Start([ConsumerAddress],1), type number) Then 
Text.BeforeDelimiter([ConsumerAddress]," ") else "0,"
```

I need to have the new (custom) column return the text before the first " " delimiter if the first character of the text is a number, otherwise return "0,".

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `Value.Is` is quite what you want. I would recommend a `try` `otherwise` construction along with `Number.FromText` like this:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Previous Step", "Custom",
      each try Number.FromText(Text.BeforeDelimiter([ConsumerAddress], " "))
           otherwise 0
  )
```

If the text before the first space can be converted to a number, then that's what you get. If it can't the `Number.FromText` throws an error and you get the `0` from the otherwise specification.

---

**Edit:** If you want the criterion for the first character only, try this:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Previous Step", "Custom",
      each if (try Number.FromText(Text.Start([ConsumerAddress], 1)) otherwise 0) <> 0
           then Text.BeforeDelimiter([ConsumerAddress], " ")
           else "0"
  )
```

This will return `"12b"` from `"12b Maple St"` whereas the first version would return `0` since `"12b"` can't be converted into a number.

Comment: Thanks. However, you didn't include the criteria that assesses the first character  of  each record - whether a number or not before parsing the try function.

Comment: Thanks. You've been very helpful.